# Is there a library etc that walks joins in property path expression in a Hibernate Restriction property

Tags: hibernate, hql

It seems irritating that property paths that involve joins must be broken down into multiple criteria. This means that code building a HQL is considerably bloated especially when the path has many joins within it. I have been unable to find a library which "internally" expands paths into the right criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write my own custom code as I couldnt find any library that expanded and inserted joins where necessary etc.